# Unable to clear the number field text box which is prefilled in mobile automation

Tags: mobile, automation, appium

Here I am using the below code with 7.2.0 Appium Client and Selenium 3.141.59 to clear the value from textbox, but it didn't work:

```java
public String clearNumid(String object, String data) {
    try {
        AndroidElement text = (AndroidElement)driver1.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty(data)));
        // Here trying to remove the text from textbox
        text.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL + " Element is not displayed";
    }
    return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the value or the text of the textbox instead of sending a back_space with sendKeys?

Answer (score 0):

You can style the code snippets by using the below command when creating a question and want to type code, this practice helps everyone, by promoting readability. [image]

As per your question, you can use [clear](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/element/actions/clear/)